# Escanear códigos de barras y mostrarlo en textbox según el prefijo y sufijo, C#

Tags: c#

En el programa que estoy haciendo necesito escanear diferentes códigos de barras por lo tanto cada código de barras lleva un respectivo textbox. Lo que necesito es escanear un código y dependiendo del prefijo y sufijo se coloque en un textbox.

Ej:

```
      codigo de barras 
                                               textbox1 
       ~200|1234~                                1234

                                                textbox2
       ~UMH|12a3~                                12a3
```

Pienso en algo asi.

```
            if (textbox1.Text.StartsWith("~200|"))
            {
                textbox1.Focus();
            }
            if (textbox2.Text.StartsWith("~UMIH|"))
            {
                textbox2.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías editar la pregunta y añadir el código que tienes hecho? Así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Para esa pregunta no he generado codigo

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo hay que sacar el caracter `~` del string que lees, por lo tanto una vez hecho el `Replace`, hago un split para separar entre prefijo y valor que quieres mostrar.

```
public void verificarLectura(){
    string lectura = txtorder.Text;
    lectura = lectura.Replace('~', ' ');
    string[] split_lectura = lectura.Split('|');
    string prefijo = split_lectura[0].Trim();
    if(prefijo == "200"){
        textbox1.Text = split_lectura[1].Trim();
    }else if(prefijo == "UMH"){
        textbox2.Text = split_lectura[1].Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Como puedo saber si el presiono la tecla ( 2 )??

Comment: A que te refieres con la tecla (2)?

Comment: si el usuario presiona el numero 2, como puedo identificarlo yo, desde el codigo??

Comment: Si no me equivoco es e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2, pero eso que tiene que ver con tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Hace mucho tiempo que no uso un código de barras pero me parece que lo que hace el código de barras de obtener el código y luego pegarlo en el objeto de texto que tenga el Focus. Podrías programar el evento TextChanged de los cuadros de texto esto te permitia obtener el texto cuando este cambie luego de eso esta fácil.

```
private void txtCodigoBarras_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = txtCodigoBarras.Text.Split('|');
    if (p[0] == "~200")
    {
        textBox1.Text = p[1];
    }
    else if (p[0] == "~UMH")
    {
        textBox2.Text = p[1];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Lectura de código de barras no esperado");
    }
}
```

Espero mi respuesta te sirva de ayuda amigo.